# Azure Service Bus - can I view scheduled messages?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Similar past question of mine: [Azure Service Bus Queue: Can I manage/cancel scheduled messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333654/azure-service-bus-queue-can-i-manage-cancel-scheduled-messages) - accepted answer here details how to cancel scheduled messages.

I'm wondering now if there's a way to view scheduled messages using the AMQP APIs. The Azure UI (and this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus._message_count_details?view=azure-java-stable) offer message counts but I can't see anything that lets me actually view those messages.

Is this a limitation of the service bus/Azure architecture? Or is there an API that will allow it? My goal would be to build a nice UI that displays scheduled tasks, and ideally I'd like to do that without maintaining that list of tasks myself outside of Azure if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, all messages can be peeked, but there's no way to peek those based on message status. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/95) on GitHub for the broker to add this feature. You can leave use-case scenario to help product team to have an idea why a feature as such would help customers.

Comment: Thanks Sean - I've put a comment on that issue. I guess since I'm not dealing with large amounts of messages just peeking client side would probably be fine.

Comment: For a small number of messages it's ok. Would be nice to see that functionality added one day.

Comment: That's what QueueExplorer does, peeks all messages but shows only scheduled ones. Yes, it's inefficient, but if shouldn't be a big deal if you use it occasionally when something goes wrong, and not in a tight loop. Service Bus API is not very friendly for these kind of applications.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some information I found useful while reading about this.

Azure Service Bus Queues allows browsing/peeking scheduled messages.
Azure Service Bus Subscriptions does not support this feature yet.

[Read More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-browsing)
[View Example](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/azure-service-bus-peek-delete-scheduled-message-which-has-future/ba-p/1648243)